# select columns from another table and create a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

ads:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|   id       |  width     |   height    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|   1        |  300       |   250       |
|   2        |  550       |   50        |
|   3        |  300       |   250       |
|   4        |  300       |   250       |
|   5        |  550       |   50        |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

assigned_ads:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|   id       |  location  |   ad_id     |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|   1        |  hp1       |   2         |
|   2        |  hp2       |   3         |
|   3        |  hp3       |   5         |
|   4        |  hp4       |   1         |
|   5        |  hp5       |   4         |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

I have `ad_id` as a foreign key...

With PHP I will be need to output the size of the ad from `ad_id` but this information is held in the `ads` table. The information I will need is `width x height`. I know there's a query I can use to create an additional column with this information but for the life of me I can't remember, or find it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: SELECT *, width * height as extracolumn...

Comment: I don't want to multiply width and height, I want to display the text `width x height`, but I get the general idea of your answer, thanks!

Comment: SELECT *, CONCAT(width,' x ', height) as extracolumn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.width, a.height
    FROM assigned_ads aa
        INNER JOIN ads a
            ON aa.ad_id = a.id
    WHERE aa.id = 123 -- Your value goes here.
```

Comment: could you explain this a little please, can't get my head around it

Comment: @LeePrice: I'm simply starting with the `assigned_ads` table and finding its related row in the `ads` table, based on a given `id` value.